# qsub job in state Eqw error: can't chdir to directory: No such file or directory

Tags: cluster, batch-jobs, cluster-ssh

I'm trying to submit a job on a cluster via *qsub*, but it gets stuck in state "*Eqw*" with error message:

```
$ qstat -j 466 | grep error
error reason    1:          09/18/2015 17:12:32 [1125:3453]: error: can't chdir to /export/home/rafaelmf: No such file or direct
```

I'm just using a test.sh script with `echo "Hello World"` output so I can try adding or removing options like *-cwd*, *-j*, *-o*.
But nothing works.

*qstat* also shows:

```
sge_o_home: /export/home/rafaelmf
sge_o_workdir: /state/partition1/home/rafaelmf
```

and I know *export* is a link to *state/partition1/*.

Also, I don't have root access, and all is done with *ssh*.
So, does anyone know how to deal with such error (without *sudo*)?

Comment: I'd guess that that directory probably isn't mounted on the job-running system, check with `df` or `ls` though (besides rebooting) fixes for such a case usually require `sudo` to correct NFS mounting problems...

Comment: That directory isn't accessible on the execution host. You can also echo commands to `qsub` to confirm this a little bit more. Try `echo 'df -h' | qsub` or `echo 'ls -l /export/home/rafaelmf' | qsub`.

Comment: `df` shows /state/partition is mounted, but /export/home/rafaelmf is not. But export -> state/partition1/. @thrig @slm

Comment: Do you have multiple qsub jobs running from within that directory?